# Direction to create a frontend/GUI for simple SQL query?

Tags: sql, user-interface, odbc, frontend

I work on a team that creates adhoc SQL queries for a large database for users that are performing research. These searches are done with Excel via ODC files with ODBC connection.

I'm looking for a program / best language suggestion to create an app for users to run the simpler queries themselves that they request. Basically a window that has a few text boxes for the variables as well as some date range boxes. Runs query and exports to a spreadsheet etc.

So far I've only found tools that run the raw SQL query code itself.

Thanks in advance. -Steve

Comment: The best tools/language would usually be the one you/your team has access to. Why not just use excel as the UI tool, mark down few cells, color code for input/output and you have the tool ready. Plus as an added bonus,  users are familiar on how to use excel.